# Looking for a typewriter font similar to this sample

Tags: font-identification

Could anybody tell me what font is used in my attached image or maybe suggest something similar to it?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Googling "typewriter fonts"?

Answer (score 4):

If you need the real typewriter look, use Trixie.

[image: Trixie]

https://www.fontfont.com/fonts/trixie/in-use

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [Courier](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/courier/regular/) or similar to-

[image]

Comment: False advertising! I tried to add it to cart, but nothing happened. I'm calling your supervisor!

Comment: @Joonas take a like for a joke :))